# How to check if event is less than 30 minutes?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am creating an events. I want to check if the event is less than 30 minutes. I don't want to allow user to add the event if it is less than 30 minutes.

I am storing the time in date format.

Date format is

```
 df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
```

I have two dates `datefrom` and `dateto`. I tried to get the minutes of `datefrom` and `dateto` and minus the from minutes from to minutes and if total minutes are less than 30 then the user can't add the event.

But it's not working well. Every time the event can't be added.

My attempt was :

```
   long frmMins = datefrom.getMinutes();

            long toMins = dateto.getMinutes();

            long calMinutes = toMins - frmMins;


 else if (calMinutes < 30) {
                        showAlert("Event can not be less than 30 Minutes.");
                    }
```

Log of event:

```
Date: Sat Mar 19 16:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016,Todate: Sat Mar 19 23:59:00 GMT+05:30 2016
```

To convert in millis and then in minutes my attempt was this:

```
       long frmMillis = datefrom.getTime();

            long frmMins = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(frmMillis);

            long toMillis = dateto.getTime();
            long toMins = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(toMillis);

            long calMinutes = toMins - frmMins;
```

But it gives minus values most of the times.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far, even though it doesn't work well ?

Comment: so you want to get time difference in a better way ?

Comment: use the unix timestamp for calculations. By using the minutes you will run into probems for times with minutes < 30.

Comment: yes. how can i check time difference is less than 30 minutes?@HammadTariqSahi

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this also -

```
long diff = dateto.getTime() - datefrom.getTime();
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
if (diffMinutes < 30) {
    showAlert("Event can not be less than 30 Minutes.");
   }
```

Comment: it shows event can not be less than 30 minutes for the time period 4:46 pm to 5:46 pm.. It goes in minus values most of times.@subodh

Comment: Are you sure, the value of `dateto=5:46 pm` and `datefrom=4:46 pm`?

Comment: i tested for 5:40 pm - 6:40 pm ,, diffMinutes it shows as 0. so it dose not allow.

Comment: Possible that, your formatter is not working properly, try to debug on the formatter and verify the formatted value.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are doing it in android i would suggest you use **`alarm manager`** to achieve this

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);
```

This sends an alarm for every half an hour. Now you need a reciver to handle the event rest is upto your app logic
here is a complete working example
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html